# jquery dies after a call to function replaceWith

Tags: jquery, replacewith

I have a web page which visitors can change using a formular in that page (a kind of wiki). The piece of code that gives me problems is listed below. This code was working fine but when I added the line of code which appears commented (a jquery `replaceWith` call) the browser executes the instruction correctly but then the page becomes irresponsive to any event that causes javascript/jquery code to execute.
Any ideas what's wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#envia").click(function(){
    objectiu = parent.frames[2].document.getElementById(parent.frames[2].id);
    substitut = '<H1>' + document.getElementById("txt1").value + '</H1>';
//  $(objectiu).replaceWith(substitut);
    $.post("xines.py",
    {
      tag: parent.frames[2].tag,            
      par: parent.frames[2].id,
      text: document.getElementById("txt1").value,      // TEXT
      codi: document.getElementById("txt2").value,      // COL·LABORADOR
      idioma: parent.frames[0].document.getElementById("txt3").value,   // IDIOMA
    },
    function(data,status){
      parent.frames[3].document.getElementById("myp").innerHTML= data;         
      parent.frames[2].document.getElementById(parent.frames[2].id).style.color='#000000';
      parent.frames[2].document.getElementById(parent.frames[2].id).innerHTML = document.getElementById("txt1").value;
      document.getElementById("txt1").value = "";
      document.getElementById("txt1").style.backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF';
    });
  });
});
```

Each element of the web page has a unique id so it is not possible that id refers to multiple elements in the web page, id is assigned in the frame 2 like follows:

```
$("p").click(function(){            // FUNCTION FOR CLICK ON <P>
    id = this.id;
    this.style.color = '#0000FF';
    parent.frames[1].document.getElementById("txt1").value = this.innerHTML;
    tag = this.nodeName;
    click_doc();
 });
$("h1").click(function(){           // FUNCTION FOR CLICK ON <H1>
    document.getElementById(id).style.color='#000000';
    this.style.color = '#0000FF';
    parent.frames[1].document.getElementById("txt1").value = this.innerHTML;
    tag = this.nodeName;
    id = this.id;
    click_doc();
 });
```

Comment: What is the actual element/HTML that is represented by `objectiu`? The jQuery `.replaceWith()` command replaces all instances, so if there're other selectors that match the one you're using, that could be the source of the problem.

Comment: Can you post the HTML that's relevant to this code? Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: objectiu can be any <p>,<h1>,<h2>,<h3> or <li> element because in frame[2] I have this code:

Comment: $("p").click(function(){   // FUNCTION FOR CLICK ON <P>
  id = this.id;
  this.style.color = '#0000FF';
     parent.frames[1].document.getElementById("txt1").value = this.innerHTML;
  tag = this.nodeName;
  click_doc();
     });
    $("h1").click(function(){   // FUNCTION FOR CLICK ON <H1>
  document.getElementById(id).style.color='#000000';
  this.style.color = '#0000FF';
     parent.frames[1].document.getElementById("txt1").value = this.innerHTML;
  tag = this.nodeName;
  id = this.id;
  click_doc();
     });

Comment: @marcel3 You should edit that into your question (with the link below your question).

Comment: The interpreter did not show any error

Comment: Thank you ajp, I'm quite novice posting here :P

Comment: @Barmar , yes there is an error in the console:

Comment: 200 OK
  1.21s 
jquery.min.js (línia 2)
POST http://usuaris.tinet.cat/marcel3/xines/xines.py
 
200 OK
  1.23s 
jquery.min.js (línia 2)
TypeError: parent.frames[2].document.getElementById(...) is null
[Break On This Error]  

...rent.frames[2].document.getElementById(parent.frames[2].id).style.color='#000000...  

what does this mean?

Comment: There are restrictions on how scripts in one frame can access other frames. I'm not sure whether they apply to your application, but that could be the problem.

Comment: And since you haven't shown the HTML, it's hard to tell what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
           objectiu = parent.frames[2].document.getElementById(parent.frames[2].id);
           substitut = '<' + noutag + ' id="' + bakid + '">' + text + '</' + noutag + '>';
           if (noutag!=parent.frames[2].tag) {
              $(objectiu).replaceWith(substitut);
           }
```